# xml to jaxb in xml cyclic references

Tags: java, jaxb

How to convert following XML to java using jaxb

```
<work>
<subwork id="sub">
<ret="it">
</subwork>
<ret id="it">
<time>9</time>
</ret>
</work>
```

It is a bit tough since ret tag  is outside subwork tag

Answer (score 0):

Frst, you need to start with valid XML.  I've made assumptions in correcting the XML:

```
<work>
    <subwork id="sub">
        <ret id="it"/>
    </subwork>
    <ret id="it">
        <time>9</time>
    </ret>
</work>
```

Second (and there are other ways of doing this), you need to create a schema that describes this XML.  Without doing it for you, I'll say that the trick is to define an element, `ret`, and then refer to that element within the `work` element and again within the `subwork` element.

Third, you then feed that schema file (.XSD) into a tool that generates the JAXB classes.  Typically this is xcj.exe (included with the Java JDK).